# XML file generation using Windows Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

Could someone tell me the best way to generate XML file with data from Windows Azure SQL database ?

Basically, I want to create a XML with data from Windows Azure SQL Database by querying certain table and the data is huge (around 90 MB). As I need to run this job at least every couple of hours, this should perform very good.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Prav

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, and not really specific to SQL Azure, so it's difficult to give you a good answer. I would suggest you research the different ways to query a SQL database, and also the different ways of writing XML. That might give you ideas for more specific questions to ask.

90MB is not particularly large - it shouldn't be difficult to that into memory. But nonetheless you might want to consider approaches that keep only a small part of the data in memory at once. eg, reading data from a `SqlDataReader` and immediately writing it to an `XmlTextWriter`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you are looking for is to query the database and have the result saved to an ADO.net DataTable. Once you have the DataTable, give it a name of your choosing using the TableName property. Then use the WriteXml method of the DataTable to save the DataTable to a location of your choosing. Make sure to specify the XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema to make sure you save the schema and the data.

Note that if the datatable is going to be 2Gb or greater, you hit the default object memory limit of .Net. One solution is to break your query into smaller chunks and store multiple datatables in XML format per original query. Another solution, is to increase the max size of an object in .Net to greater than 2Gb. This comes with it's own set of risks and performance issues. However, to exceed that 2Gb object size restriction, make sure that you're application is 64 bit, the application is compiled to .Net 4.5 or later and the app.config file should have gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true".

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string someConnectionString = "enter Aure connection string here";
DataTable someDataTable = new DataTable();
SqlConnection someConnection = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString);
someConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader someReader = null;
// enter your query below
SqlCommand someCommand = new SqlCommand(("SELECT * FROM [SomeTableName]"), someConnection);
// Since your are downloading a large amount of data, I effectively turned the timeout off in the line below
someCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
someReader = someCommand.ExecuteReader();
someDataTable.Load(someReader);
someConnection.Close();
// you need to name the datatable before saving it in XML
someDataTable.TableName = "anyTableName";
string someFileNameAndLocation = @"C:\Backup\backup1.xml";
// the XmlWriteMode is necessary to save the schema and data of the datatable
someDataTable.WriteXml(someFileNameAndLocation, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```